# ERROR PYTHON + SELENIUM: "ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x00000204BC8954E0>, but it must be an int, float or None."

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, edge

Estoy aprendiendo python. Ya puedo hacer solicitudes con la librería "requests" y BeautifulSoup sin mucho problema. Ahora estoy intentando aprender a hacer solicitudes usando la librería "selenium" pero apenas ejecuto el código (anexo) me arroja un error (anexo también). Intenté buscar en internet pero no consegui información precisa que me pueda ayuadr.

***DATO IMPORTANTE:** muchos tutoriales en internet usan el webdriver de chrome. Pero yo quiero usar el webdriver de microsoft Edge.*

---

Código en python:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

ruta = r'./msedgedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Edge(ruta)
```

El error que me arroja:

```
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x00000204BC8954E0>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Answer (score 0):

te paso con los scripts que lo ejecuto yo:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path=r'C: acá agregale la ruta de tu driver \msedgedriver')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)

driver.get("dominio de cualquier pagina para probar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve haciendo unas pruebas porque tuve el mismo problema y lo pude solucionar reinstalando el modulo urllib3 con una versión anterior, podrías intentar con la siguiente línea:

```
pip install urllib3==1.26.6
```

ya que con la versión 2 genera este error que mencionas. En mi caso uso selenium 3.141.0